# Disclaimer - suggested wording

Tags: reporting-services

I'm conscious that the data I report out with Reporting Services can only be as good as what's coming in, etc; that no data is ever going to be 100% accurate.

As such, I would like to add a disclaimer to my reports.

Does anyone here do this and if so, what wording do you use?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should be asking this on a legal forum, this is pretty off-topic for a programming forum.

Comment: Thanks and apologies, I thought the forum could take into account data quality issues, etc. It's not so much a legal thing, it's more that my users are aware that what they're seeing may not be 100% accurate. I shall think a bit more before posting next time.

Comment: Even though this may be off-topic, I'm a bit curious about this.  I've always just spent most of my time validating data to ensure the lack of necessity of a statement like this.